# Magento 2 installation stuck at 67%

Tags: magento2

```
Module 'Magento_Theme':
Installing data..
```

The installation gets stuck at the above step from the log. There is no additional errors, does anyone know what could be causing this? I should point out that I use installation with sample data

Comment: ckd xdebug.max_nesting_level=50000; at php.ini

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question here. I changed

```
memory_limit = 2048M
```

inside .user.ini file in the root of the magento folder.